# Rename and Increment Integer File Names

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of files with integers that range from `30.pdf` to `133.pdf` as filenames. What I am trying to do is increment each filename, so `30.pdf` should become `31.pdf`, ..., and `133.pdf` should become `134.pdf`.

**Does anybody know how I can achieve this?**

I know I can loop through the directory with `foreach ($f in dir)` or display and even sort the filenames with `get-childitem | sort-object`, but this latter method obviously has issues sorting numerically.

No idea why something so simple is so difficult to figure out. Cannot find this anywhere online...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work assuming the `BaseName` of the files contains only digits as you have shown on your question. First you would need to sort the files *descending* to avoid collision and after that you can pipe them to [`Rename-Item` using the `-NewName` *script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.2#example-4--rename-multiple-files):

```
Get-ChildItem path/to/files -File | Sort-Object { [int]$_.BaseName } -Descending |
Rename-Item -NewName {
    [int]$n = $_.BaseName; '{0}{1}' -f (++$n), $_.Extension
}
```

Comment: this worked. for future reference, is there any way to omit some or a range of the files possibly with an `if/else` statement?

Comment: @oldboy for sure, `Get-ChildItem` has many filtering capabilities ( `-Filter` / `-Include` / `-Exclude` ) but in case it's not possible to filter using it you would likely need to use a filtering cmdlet such as `Where-Object`.

Comment: ahhh ok, so the "flags" like `-filter`, `-include`, etc are basically like "methods," whereas "cmdlets" are like "functions" for a lack of better words?

Comment: @oldboy yes, what you call flags are known as cmdlet _"Paramaters"_ and _cmdlet_ can be called a function but according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview?view=powershell-7.2#cmdlets): _"This includes binary (C#) cmdlets, advanced script functions, CDXML, and Workflows."_

Comment: thanks brother. where is the official documentation located?

Comment: @oldboy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/ would be a good start point.

Answer (score 0):

We can take some shortcuts to make this easier since your file names are literally just integers.  Start by using this statement to get a collection of integers that represents your files ($files is the output of Get-ChildItems from the parent directory):

```
$integersFromNames = $files | Select -ExpandProperty BaseName | foreach { $_ -as [int] } | sort ‐Descending
```

Now you have all of the existing files sorted from largest to smallest. You can use [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.2) in a foreach loop to get you the rest of the way:

```
foreach ($oldNumber in $integersFromNames) {
    $newNumber = $oldNumber + 1
    Rename-Item -Path "$oldNumber.pdf" -NewName "$newNumber.pdf"
}
```

Please excuse any typos. I'm on my phone. Hopefully  the concept comes across clearly.

Comment: this is prone to the same sorting issue. its sorting the values as strings instead of integers when u log `$integersFromNames`, unless im missing something. however, this wouldnt be a problem -- i mean, sorting wouldnt even be necessary -- if the file system allowed u to choose the names of each file before committing them so to speak i.e. **mustnt we first rename `133` to `134` and work backwards to prevent duplicate filenames?** ur solution appears like it would work if the sorting issue was fixed