# Powershell code that makes all files in all folders in a subfolders renamed after the folders they are in numbered up

Tags: powershell

One line code:

```
$A = get-location ; $dir = Get-ChildItem $A | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} ; $dir | ForEach-Object {Set-Location $_.FullName ; $B = $_.Name ; dir | %{$x=0} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$B - ($x).pdf"; $x++ }}; cd ..
```

Command by command code:

```
$A = get-location
$dir = Get-ChildItem $A | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} 
$dir | ForEach-Object {Set-Location $_.FullName $B = $_.Name dir | %{$x=0} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$B - ($x).pdf"; $x++ }}
cd ..
```

Comment: Take a look at [Santiago's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70818693/14903754). Might be what you're after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$A = get-location
```

> Saves the current location in variable $A

```
$dir = Get-ChildItem $A | ? {$_.PSIsContainer}
```

> Saves the Sub files of the current location in variable $dir

```
$dir | ForEach-Object {Set-Location $_.FullName $B = $_.Name dir | %{$x=0} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$B - ($x).pdf"; $x++ }}
```

> `$dir | ForEach-Object {COMMAND}` <--THIS MAKES IT DO A COMMAND FOR EACH FOLDER

> `{Set-Location $_.FullName $B = $_.Name dir |` <--THIS MAKES IT CD IN EACH LOCATION AND SAVES THE NAME OF THE FILE IT'S IN ON VARIABLE $B

> `%{$x=0} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$B - ($x).pdf"; $x++ }}` <--  RENAMES ALL FILES WITH VARIABLE $B AND NUMBERS THE END OFF IT UNTILL THERE ARENT ANY FILES SO IT CAN GO TO ANOTHER SUB FOLDER

Comment: It's great that you want to share a solution; sharing it will be more effective if you [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).